# Mapbox: How can I get the scale of the zoomlevel from Mapbox?

Tags: zooming, scale, mapbox, meter

Is it possible to get a list of meter correspond to zoom level of Mapbox? Just like listed below from Bing map: [here](https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2006/02/25/map-control-zoom-levels-gt-resolution)

[image: Bing map scale]

Comment: Note that the table above is only accurate at the Equator. The ratio of meters to pixels varies considerably by latitude.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, right in the Mapbox documentation:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/zoom-level/#zoom-levels-and-geographical-distance